# Parameter is not passing by ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have an ajax call to a function in my controller. I need to pass a parameter to that function but it is not happening. My ajax call:

```
 $("#BTN_Plus").click(function () {
     var CurrentPage = @Model.CurrentPage;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Accueil/ListerIncidentsHotline",
        data: JSON.stringify(CurrentPage),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Affichage").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The function in my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult ListerIncidentsHotline( int page = 1)
    {
            int NextPage = 1 + page;
            const int PageSize = 10;
            int NumDossier = StructureData.DonneNumDossier((string)Session["Utilisateur"], (string)Session["MotDePasse"]);
            IEnumerable<IncidentHotline> ListeIncidents = StructureData.DonneIncidentsHotline(NumDossier);
            int NbreIncidents = StructureData.DonneNombreIncidents(NumDossier);
            ViewBag.NombreIncidents = NbreIncidents;
            var viewModel = new IncidentsPageInfo()
            {
                NumPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)ListeIncidents.Count() / PageSize),
                CurrentPage = NextPage,
                PageSize = PageSize,
                Incidents = ListeIncidents.Skip((NextPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize),
            };
            return this.PartialView(viewModel);

    }
```

When I make an alert of the variable **CurrentPage**, it shows me the right value, but when it comes to the ajax call, i get an error saying that the parameter is null. Can't figure out what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

well as a data you need to pass a numerable value with the name of page, change your ajax data

`$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Accueil/ListerIncidentsHotline",
    data: JSON.stringify(CurrentPage),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#Affichage").html(data);
    }
});`

change data to  `data: {page: CurrentPage}`

Comment: it works! i just dont know what is your input id!you have to use something like, page: $("#CurrentPage").val()

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier....

```
$.get("/Accueil/ListerIncidentsHotline", { CurrentPage: @Model.CurrentPage } ).
  done(function (data) {
    $("#Affichage").html(data);
   });
```

Comment: I can't use the get method because in the controller I have already a function with the same name for the get method.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the problem came out of my ajax call. So I have to concatenate the name of the parameter with its value inside the method JSON.Stringify, as below:

```
$("#BTN_Plus").click(function () {
    var CurrentPage = @Model.CurrentPage;
    alert(CurrentPage);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Accueil/ListerIncidentsHotline",
        data: JSON.stringify({ page: CurrentPage }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Affichage").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```